# Add html inside any tag without javascript

Tags: php, domdocument

**Guys, I have a problem. Is there a way to add html inside a tag without using javascript using only php anyway ?. Thank you very much for your help in advance.**

> For example, there is this code:

```php
<?php
// This part is required here, because she comes another function.
// It's generate from php server, I need to show inside tag body, for example.
$code = "<h1 style='display:none' id='title'>My String</h1>";
echo $code;
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="my-div"></div>

    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js'
     integrity='sha512-b6lGn9+1aD2DgwZXuSY4BhhdrDURVzu7f/PASu4H1i5+CRpEalOOz/HNhgmxZTK9lObM1Q7ZG9jONPYz8klIMg=='
      crossorigin='anonymous'></script>

    <script>
        $('#my-div').html($('#titulo').html());
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

> The output is this in the source code:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

In the browser, the output is this **My String**:
But, this manipulation is the gift, which uses javascript for this. I don't want it that way. This will not do, because the code will be shown at the top, before the `<! DOCTYPE html>` tag. Is it possible, on the server, to insert `<h1 style ='display:none' id='title'> My String </h1>` inside the boby tag, for example?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> **How I would like it to look:**

### Example 2

For example, I have this file with code:
file2.php
[image]

```php
<?php
include "file2.php";
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="my-div">
        I want to show "<h1>My String</h1>" here.
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yes you can: you can generate html serverside with PHP.

Comment: // This part is required here, because she comes another function.
// It's generate from php server, I need to show inside tag body, for example.
$code = "<h1 style='display:none' id='title'>My String</h1>";
echo $code;

Comment: @TaffarelXavier explain in depth how you get this code and what you can manipulate.

Comment: I add an another image with file2.php as example.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it as simple as this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="my-div">
       <?php
       $code = "<h1 style='display:none' id='title'>My String</h1>";
       echo $code; 
       ?>
    </div>

    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js'
     integrity='sha512-b6lGn9+1aD2DgwZXuSY4BhhdrDURVzu7f/PASu4H1i5+CRpEalOOz/HNhgmxZTK9lObM1Q7ZG9jONPYz8klIMg=='
      crossorigin='anonymous'></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: // This part is required here, because she comes another function.
// It's generate from php server, I need to show inside tag body, for example.
$code = "<h1 style='display:none' id='title'>My String</h1>";
echo $code;

Answer (score -1):

PHP is a server side scripting language and will only parse PHP code on the server side.
Yes, you can place HTML code inside PHP variables like you have done, but that will get rendered into the client (your browser).

What you can do is place `$code` variable inside the target div, like this:

```
<div id="my-div"><?php echo $code; ?></div>
```

Give it a try

Comment: // This part is required here, because she comes another function.
// It's generate from php server, I need to show inside tag body, for example.
$code = "<h1 style='display:none' id='title'>My String</h1>";
echo $code;